# Error using parfor inside spmd block - matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor, spmd

As I know about parallel programming in Matlab, We can exactly specify what worker does what; using :

```
if labindex == x 
    %some computations
end
```

Also we can run `for` loops in parallel; using :

```
parfor i1 = x:y
    %some computations
end
```

I'm using a cluster with a few nodes and each node has 8 cores.
I want to run 2 functions which each one contains an `parfor` loop, and each function get executed by an worker, my code is something like this :

```
spmd
    if labindex == 1
        alpha  = forward( some parameters );
    end
    if labindex == 2
        beta  = backward( some parameters );
    end
end
```

I wanted these 2 functions get executed simultaneously by 2 different nodes.
but Matlab throws back this error :

```
PARFOR or SPMD can not be used inside an SPMD block.
```

Why is that so?
Any idea?

Comment: Added relevant pointers in Matlab documentation. It doesn't seem like your code should throw an error (not according to the latest Matlab documentation, at least), so you should provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want to get further help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in [`parfor`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/nesting-and-flow-in-parfor-loops.html) documentation:

> The body of a `parfor`-loop cannot contain another `parfor`-loop. But it
>   can call a function that contains another `parfor`-loop.
>
> However, **because a worker cannot open a parallel pool**, a worker cannot
>   run the inner nested `parfor`-loop in parallel. This means that only one
>   level of nested `parfor`-loops can run in parallel. If the outer loop
>   runs in parallel on a parallel pool, the inner loop runs serially on
>   each worker. If the outer loop runs serially in the client (e.g.,
>   `parfor` specifying zero workers), the function that contains the inner
>   loop can run the inner loop in parallel on workers in a pool.

Same is true for [`spmd`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/execute-simultaneously-on-multiple-data-sets.html#bvflxs1-7) statements:

> The body of an `spmd` statement cannot directly contain another `spmd`.
>   However, it can call a function that contains another `spmd` statement.
>   The inner `spmd` statement does not run in parallel in another parallel
>   pool, but runs serially in a single thread on the worker running its
>   containing function.

It appears that you can actually have nested `spmd`/`parfor` as long as they are encapsulated in functions, but they will still not run in parallel, so there's no point.

Comment: Your answer is clear, but consider that each worker (node of the cluster that I'm using) has a cpu with 8 cores. and in `SPMD` block I'm assigning each worker a function that contains a `PARFOR`. which means the worker can open a parallel pool itself. so what will happen in this situation? does the `PARFOR` loops get executed in parallel?

Comment: Doesn't matter how many cores the workers have since they cannot open parallel pool themselves.This is a limitation of Matlab which is clearly described in the documentation I cited. You need to either refactor your code to avoid nested `parfor`/`spmd`, or else span multiple matlab instances yourself instead of relying on `spmd`to do that for you.